# Regarding grep in solaris

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want grep for a particular work in multiple files. Multiple files  are stored in variable testing.

```
TESTING=$(ls -tr *.txt)

echo $TESTING
test.txt ab.txt bc.txt

grep "word" "$TESTING"
grep: can't open test.txt
ab.txt
bc.txt
```

Giving me an error. Is there any other way to do it other than for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the double quotes out from around `$TESTING`.

```
grep "word" $TESTING
```

The double quotes are making your whole file list expand to a single argument to `grep`.  The *right* way to do this is:

```
find . -name \*.txt -print0 | xargs -0 grep "word"
```

Comment: You're assuming he wants to grep files in subdirectories.  If not, then I think you're stuck with: grep word *.txt.

Comment: @pra, true - definitely better than his approach.

Answer (score 0):

No quotes needed I guess.

```
grep "word" $TESTING
```

works for me (Ubuntu, bash).